# Где лучше использовать Json файл для товаров интернет магазина?

Tags: json, reactjs

У меня есть задача сделать простенький интернет-магазин на React. Я хочу, чтобы товары в нём были динамическими и их можно было изменять, удалять и добавлять. Лучше способа, чем Json файл я не придумал(очень понравилось отправлять запрос на сервер и получать json данные, которые потом и отрисовывать). Вот только куда лучше поместить свой собственный Json я не знаю, хотелось бы, конечно, отправлять запрос на какой-нибудь сервер и получать мой Json, а не хранить его просто в папке проекта(есть мысль поместить Json файл на гит и обращаться к нему, но ещё не пробовал, чтобы узнать возможно ли это вообще).
Как можно понять -  я новичок в этом деле и возможно что-то намудрил, поэтому поправьте меня, если я мыслю что-то не так.

Comment: что плохого что в том, чтобы хранить json локально?

Comment: Мне говорили, что так нигде не делается, всегда через апи. Поэтому и хочется нечто подобное.

Comment: почему тогда не спросите того, кто так сказал?